# Pow() calculates wrong?

Tags: c++, pow

I need to use pow in my c++ program and if i call the `pow()` function this way:

```
long long test = pow(7, e);
```

Where

> e is an integer value with the value of 23.

I always get `821077879` as a result. If i calculate it with the windows calculator i get `27368747340080916343`.. Whats wrong here? ):

I tried to cast to different types but nothing helped here... What could be the reason for this? How i can use `pow()` correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't `pow` return a `long double` not a `long long`?

Comment: With long double i get 821077879.00000000 as a result which is still wrong..

Comment: @EricPetroelje `pow()` returns a `double`, which is converted to `long long` upon assignment to `test`. The overflow in the conversion is undefined behavior (some platforms have a hardware exception for this overflow).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The result is doesn't fit in `long long`.

If you want to deal with very big numbers then use a library like [GMP](http://gmplib.org/)

Or store it as a floating point (which won't be as precise).

Applying modulo:

```
const unsigned int b = 5; // base
const unsigned int e = 27; // exponent
const unsigned int m = 7; // modulo

unsigned int r = 1; // remainder

for (int i = 0; i < e; ++i)
  r = (r * b) % m;

// r is now (pow(5,27) % 7)
```

Comment: Is there another way for just this one case? I don't want to implement a whole library in my program for one specific line of code..

Comment: @user1004012 Store it as a floating point `long double` instead of an integer.

Comment: As written above, i get the same result: "With long double i get 821077879.00000000 as a result which is still wrong.." What's wrong?

Comment: that's working correctly, thank you. but if i want to apply the modulo operation to the double value the next problem appears.. how to calculate modulo on such a big value?

Comment: @user1004012 You can't on floating points. What exactly is your problem? It may be doable if you post your entire problem instead of what you think is the problem.

Comment: @user1004012 I've posted how you can find the modulo.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29 i try to implement this.. everything is working except the encryption line were it says: c = m^e (mod n).. this line i want to implement correctly in an c++ apllication.

Comment: oh, haven't seen your response as i posted the last message.. will try this, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

7<sup>23</sup> is too big to fit into a `long long` (assuming it's 64 bits).  The value is getting truncated.

**Edit:** Oh, why didn't you say that you wanted `pow(b, e) % m` instead of just `pow(b, e)`?  That makes things a whole lot simpler, because you don't need bigints after all.  Just do all your arithmetic mod `m`.  Pubby's solution works, but here's a faster one (O(log e) instead of O(e)).

```
unsigned int powmod(unsigned int b, unsigned int e, unsigned int m)
{
   assert(m != 0);

   if (e == 0)
   {
      return 1;
   }
   else if (e % 2 == 0)
   {
      unsigned int squareRoot = powmod(b, e / 2, m);
      return (squareRoot * squareRoot) % m;
   }
   else
   {
      return (powmod(b, e - 1, m) * b) % m;
   }
}
```

Comment: So which kind of type should i use then? I wanted to implement this in my rsa function..

Comment: ... and the Windows Calculator handles it because from some version onwards they plugged in an arbitrary-precision library to handle the math.

Answer (score 4):

See it live: https://ideone.com/YsG7V

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
int main()
{
    long double ldbl = pow(7, 23);
         double dbl  = pow(7, 23);
    std::cout << ldbl << ", " << dbl << std::endl;
}
```

Output: 2.73687e+19, 2.73687e+19

Comment: how to use this with variable names? in which variable type should i store the result?